# Shortcode displaying at top of wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a page that displays my members information from a sql database. I have the output in the form of a shortcode but the information is displaying above the page content even though the shortcode is placed at the very bottom of the text editor. I know the problem is due to this code echoing instead of returning but I am a newbie to php and need help with syntax.

```
function listMembers() {
$sql1=mysql_query("select state_id,state_name from ".TABLE_STATE);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
    ?> <a href="#" onclick="getDetails(
<?php echo $row1["state_id"];?>)"> <?php echo $row1["state_name"]; ?>
```

Here is all of the code

```
$sql1=mysql_query("select state_id,state_name from ".TABLE_STATE);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
    ?> <a href="#" onclick="getDetails(<?php echo $row1["state_id"];?>)"> <?php echo       $row1["state_name"]; ?> </a> &nbsp;<?php

}
?><br/><br/><div id="resultDiv"></div><?php

}
add_shortcode('memberlist', 'listMembers');

function listRescueStandards() {

$display_members = '';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vc.*, s.*, m.*
    FROM ".TABLE_COMPLIANCE." vc, ".TABLE_STATE." s, ".TABLE_MEMBERS." m
    WHERE vc.member_id = m.cid
    AND m.status = '1'
    AND m.state = s.state_abbr
    ORDER BY m.state, m.organization ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $organization = stripslashes($row['organization']);

    if ($row['website']) {
        $link = "<a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'>";
        $endlink = "</a>";
    } else {
        $link = "";
        $endlink = "";
    }

    if($x!=$row['state_name']){
        $display_members .= "<br /><strong>".strtoupper($row['state_name'])."</strong><br />";
        $x = $row['state_name'];
    }

    $display_members .= $link.$organization.$endlink."<br />
       ".stripslashes($row['address'])." ".stripslashes($row['address2'])."<br />
       ".stripslashes($row['city']).", ".stripslashes($row['state'])."  ".$row['zip']."<br />";

    if ($row['contact_name']) $display_members .= "Contact:   ".stripslashes($row['contact_name']);
    if ($row['contact_title'])  $display_members .= ", ".stripslashes($row['contact_title']);
    if ($row['phone'])      $display_members .= "<br />Tel: ".stripslashes($row['phone']);
    if ($row['fax'])    $display_members .= "<br />Fax: ".stripslashes($row['fax']);
    if ($row['email'])  $display_members .= "<br />".$row['email'];
    if ($row['website'])        $display_members .= "<br /><a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'>".$row['website']."</a>";
    if ($row['year_est'])       $display_members .= "<br />Founded in ".$row['year_est'].".";
    if ($row['org501c3'] == "1")        $display_members .= "<br />This organization IS registered with the IRS as a 501(c)3.";
    if ($row['org501c3'] != "1")    $display_members .= "<br />This organization is NOT     registered with the IRS as a 501(c)3.";

    $display_members .= "<br /><br />";
}
        return "<div class='memberlist'>" . $display_members . "</div>";

}
add_shortcode('standardslist', 'listRescueStandards');
  ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help! I appreciate anyone looking at this and if you need clarification, please let me know!

Comment: post more code. what is the shortcode? what function is the shortcode associated with? a shortcode would be associated with a special shortcode function which presumably is calling the function you posted. For a wordpress shortcode you should add the `wordpress` tag to your question

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've added the rest of the code for the page and updated the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah OK. according the [shortcodes api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) you want to be returning a value, not echoing it. you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to convert an `echo` type of code to a `return` type. This entails simply wrapping all of your `echo` statements in `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`

```
function listMembers() {
$sql1=mysql_query("select state_id,state_name from ".TABLE_STATE);
ob_start(); //send all future echo statements to the buffer instead of output

while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
    ?> <a href="#" onclick="getDetails(<?php echo $row1["state_id"];?>)"> <?php echo       $row1["state_name"]; ?> </a> &nbsp;<?php

}
?><br/><br/><div id="resultDiv"></div><?php


$result=ob_get_clean(); //capture the buffer into $result
return $result; //return it, instead of echoing

}
```